# How do I use JFrame.pack()?

Tags: java, jframe, pack

How I can use `pack()` and what is it doing?

For example:

```
//1. Create the frame.
JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");

//2. Optional: What happens when the frame closes?
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//3. Create components and put them in the frame.
//...create emptyLabel...
frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

//4. Size the frame.  (How does pack() set the frame size???)
frame.pack();

//5. Show it.
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Read the javadoc. It tells you what every method of every class does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of the method is specified in the documentation (the javadoc).

Here's the documentation for [`Window.pack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29).

> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents. The resulting width and height of the window are automatically enlarged if either of dimensions is less than the minimum size as specified by the previous call to the setMinimumSize method.

Answer (score 0):

[`pack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack()) changes the size of your [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) to the smallest possible size that will still hold all the elements you've put in it.

Comment: In this case, it will consider the "preferred size" of all added components, right?